# CSOM Error "Column does not exist" when creating a new column

Tags: sharepoint-server, csom, jsom

When using JSOM to add a new site column to a 2013 SharePoint web, I get the following error

> Column 'ProgramName' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user. https://server.org/it-test/jpaugh/awesomeSite

I'm using the following code. Am I doing this correctly?

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current()
var fields = context.get_web().get_fields();
var formatted = "<field Name='ProgramName' DisplayName='Program Name' Required='true'"
   + " Group='Awesome' Type='Text' MaxLength='100'></field>";
fields.addFieldAsXml(formatted, false, SP.AddFieldOptions.addFieldCheckDisplayName);
context.executeQueryAsync(success, failure);


function success() {
    console.log("Request success");
}
function failure(sender, args) {
    console.error("Request failed: " + args.get_message());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies with the case of the `<field>` and `</field>` tag.

It should be `<Field>` and `</Field>`. Its case sensitive.

Also, to make it required, it needs to `TRUE`.

So, try the below code. Works at my end :

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current()
var fields = context.get_web().get_fields();
var formatted = "<Field Name='ProgramName' DisplayName='Program Name' Required='TRUE'"
   + " Group='Awesome' Type='Text' MaxLength='100'></Field>";
fields.addFieldAsXml(formatted, false, SP.AddFieldOptions.addFieldCheckDisplayName);
context.executeQueryAsync(success, failure);


function success() {
    console.log("Request success");
}
function failure(sender, args) {
    console.error("Request failed: " + args.get_message());
}
```

Reference [Field element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa979575.aspx)